# Is an event with a fixed number of outcomes considered random if one outcome is more likely than another?

Tags: probability, random

My friend says that even though an event has (for example) three outcomes with outcome A at 10 percent, outcome B at 10 percent, and outcome C at 80 percent that the outcome of the event is still random and I’m saying that it’s not random.

There is some literature about ‘degrees of randomness’ but it’s all kind of new stuff.  Perhaps that has some relevance here?

Comment: Consider rolling two $6$ sided dice. The most likely outcome is $7$ because there are more ways to get a $7$ than any other number but the outcome is still random.

Comment: Or just put colored stickers over the faces of one six-sided die: one red sticker, one blue sticker, four yellow stickers. The probability of "yellow" is $4/6$ but rolling the die is still a random process.

Comment: Still random.  Something can even be considered random if some outcome has probability $1$... for instance, choosing a real number uniformly at random from $[0,1]$ yields an irrational with probability $1$, but it's still random whether it yields a rational.  What you want to say is something like, "The choice between outcomes $A$, $B$, and $C$ is random, but it isn't *uniformly* random."

Comment: It is still random but your intuition is correct - it is less random than equiviprobable outcomes. You can use [entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_(information_theory)) to describe how random an event is - the higher the entropy, the more random the state of the system is. If entropy is $0$, the system is no longer random.

Answer (score 0):

Your friend is correct. The term random in common usage includes events that have different probabilities of occurring.

Situations where all events have equal probabilities are just special cases. They are of interest, but random includes much more.